# With Passenger where does the console log (output from puts) go ... for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, passenger, centos6

I am running my botkit nodejs application behind passenger but it is not showing any kind of error in the logging system I configure (`winston.Logger`)... So I would like to check the out put of all `console.log` that I have in the application but I don't know where I can find it since it seems to be consumed by Passenger.

Where can I find that?

Answer (score 0):

I found it is was in the  root of my application.... as passenger.xxx.log where xxx is the port I configured my passenger to listen on.

Comment: When Passenger is used with Apache with a default config then Apache's error log file is used. This includes stdout and stderr from the application.

See: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/log_file/